# Opening an image on click with new tab

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my application, I have created a small preview of attachment uploaded earlier. So here to open it, need to right click of the preview and need to select open in new tab.

Other than selecting, how can I change this when user click the image open it on the new tab?

```
<td>
<img alt="" width="100"  height="100" class="ml-1" src="@Url.Action("RetrieveImage", new { id = item.Id } )"
</td>
```

I have tried this, but then It's shows error in the Item pass to get the image

```
<img alt="" width="100"  height="100" class="ml-1" src="@Url.Action("RetrieveImage", new { id = item.Id } , new { @target="_blank"})"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add image as nested tag to **a** and give it **target=_blank** value as below

```
<a href="@Url.Action("RetrieveImage", new { id = item.Id })" target="_blank">
    <img width="220" height="250" border="0" align="center"  src="@Url.Action("RetrieveImage", new { id = item.Id })"/>
</a>
```

Comment: I tried this and it worked. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The above Answer is correct but, I would recommend adding `rel="noreferrer noopener"`. As there are security concerns with just using `target="_blank"`.
Setting `noopener noreferrer` prevents phishing attacks.
Check out this article : [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-use-html-to-open-link-in-new-tab/)

```html
<a href="your-url" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">

        <img alt="" width="100"  height="100" class="ml-1">
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your information. I will try this also